# Remapping Mouse Clicks with Keystrokes on macOS

Tags: macos, keyboard-shortcuts

Looking for macOS app that can remap the two thumb buttons on a mouse to simulate a combination of keystrokes.  This software should be compatible with macOS Ventura and can be paid for.

The software should prevent the button click from registering with the active window.  Instead, it should cause that click to be ignored and simulate the keyboard keystrokes as a replacement.

Would also be great if different rules could be set up with different applications.

Example setup using [X-Button Mouse](https://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/xmousebuttoncontrol.htm) on Windows:

[image: X-Button Mouse example on Winodws]

Answer (score 1):

I think [SteerMouse](https://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/) should be able to do all you need.

[image]

There's also [USB Overdrive](https://www.usboverdrive.com/index.php/information/) though I've never used that one myself.